# Apache Phoenix: Values in UPSERT must evaluate to a constant. java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 204 (22008)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I want to update a table named EMPLOYEE in hbase, which looks like the following and the row key is ID.

```
ID,Name,Age
"1","John","34"
"2","David","22"
```

I want to add another column named City in this table. Using Apache phoenix I executed this command first to alter the existing schema.

```
ALTER TABLE "EMPLOYEE" ADD IF NOT EXISTS "CITY" VARCHAR(40)
```

This command executed successfully. Then I tried to insert values. Using the following command.

```
UPSERT INTO "EMPLOYEE" ("ID","CITY") VALUES ("1", "London")
```

However every time I execute this, I get the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 204 (22008): Values in UPSERT must evaluate to a constant.
```

What is it what I am missing here, that is causing the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the error, Changing double quotes to single quotes worked for me -

```
UPSERT INTO "EMPLOYEE" ("ID","CITY") VALUES ('1', 'London')
```

Answer (score 0):

String literal values should be in single quotations, `'`.